# Direction of terminal blocks in PCB layout

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am designing a PCB and I cannot find the direction of the terminal blocks. I.E on which side of the terminal block the holes are facing. I believe they are currently looking down but I cannot find any documentation on this [image: PCB layout, terminal blocks are at the bottom]

This is eagle by the way.

Comment: Use a terminal block with proper documentation.

Comment: I tend to buy samples of unfamiliar parts - having one in your hand is a great help visualising how it will work on the PCB - or fit in the enclosure. Usually cheaper than time spent thinking or asking questions here.

Comment: I sense an autorouter. It's a simple design, don't use the autorouter -- It looks like crap.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the terminal block datasheet. You want to pick the terminal block and use a footprint that fits the terminal block, not pick some random footprint out of the library and try to find a terminal block that matches it.

For [example](http://www.on-shore.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/ostvnxxa150.pdf):

[image]

From the drawing you can easily see that the wires enter from the 'bottom' of the recommended hole layout.

It would also be normal to label the terminal block from left to right, looking into the wire entry holes.

Make sure the hole sizes are appropriate (number one cause of disappointment with through-hole boards) and you can probably increase the size of the pads to make it more robust.

Answer (score 1):

That footprint looks pretty much symetrical to me - the terminal block could be inserted in the board either way.

For something like this, you should get an actual part to look at (and measure) while doing the board layout.  You may find that the horizontal line just below the pins matches a feature on the terminal block, so it may be used as a guide as to which way the terminal block is facing.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers on PCB headers are arbitrary. If Eagle has designated numbers then choose which way you wish to have the "orientation offset tab" by your interconnect plug.  It probably does not matter as long as they match at both ends. In which case if you are interfacing to something else look up the details for pin #.  Don't Guess . Murphy's Law.

[image]

Standard layout is top view for numbering.